# DNSSEC - DNS/domain providers that enable DANE DNS records

Tags: postfix, bind, dnssec

Our company registered domain "example.eu" with [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/en) which has a "one click solution" to enable the DNSSEC for our domain's zone. So we enabled it, waited until [dnsviz](https://dnsviz.net/) inspection tool showed us that our parent zone (.eu) got the ***hashed*** **public KSK** from Gandi and they published it in their DS record that now authenticates our zone "example.eu").

We were also expecting from Gandi to send us the **private KSK** so that we could continue the chain of trust but they haven't sent anything. On their site it is also impossible to add any kind of DNSSEC DNS records like TLSA, DS...

So it looks like they support DNSSEC but don't support DANE authentication... Probably they would loose some buisness because DANE works with **self-signed certifficates** and would prevent companies like Gandi to make easy money by playing a role of CA and selling certifficates. DANE is a direct replacement for system of stupid CA authorities that works with self-signed certifficates!

**So does anyone know of a better domain registrar that would offer us ability to manually add DANE records like DS, TLSA...?**

We need TLSA records support in order to authenticate Postfix e-mail server using DANE and we need DS records support to authenticate any other physical machine using DANE and therefore continue a chain of trust.

Comment: "We were also expecting from Gandi to send us the private KSK so that we could continue the chain of trust but they haven't sent anything." You seem to have misconception on how DNSSEC works. If the company is your DNS provider (no matter if it is your registrar or not) you provide it with records but the provider deals with DNSSEC and hence as nothing to send to you in that regard. If you manage the nameservers yourself, then DNSSEC is on you and you just have to send your DS, through your registrar, to the registry for the secure delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gandi supports DANE `TLSA` records and further secure delegation (`DS` records) via their [LiveDNS API](https://doc.livedns.gandi.net/#recordtype):

> **RecordType**
>
> One of :
>
> A, AAAA, ALIAS (not yet supported with dnssec-enabled domains), CAA,
> CDS, CNAME, DNAME, DS, KEY, LOC, MX, NS, OPENPGPKEY, PTR, SPF, SRV,
> SSHFP, TLSA, TXT, WKS